# MySql Query to display a record with time condition

Tags: php, mysql

For example i am posting a news via admin and mentioning the start date as 25-02-2011 and end date as 28-02-2011. It will display in the user side on 25the feb 2011.

If i post a news via admin on start date as 26-02-2011 and end date as 28-02-2011 then it will display the news on 26-02-2011.

If i didn't post anything on 27-02-2011 and 28-02-2011 it should display the last posted news. **That is in this case it should display the news which is posted on 26-02-2011 for both 27-02-2011 and 28-02-2011.**

**EDIT: "SELECT id, title FROM news WHERE startDate  >= CURDATE() AND

expiryDate <= CURDATE() AND status='Active' ORDER BY id DESC". There is a news in current date. It is not even fetching that record. What change to be done.**

How can this be done using mysql.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If this is a website you are talking about, please mention the server side technology you are using. For example is it using php?
Because what you are asking for, can not be accomplished just by using mysql.

Comment: MySQL has many date functions which can return the current date for exemple, it's quite easy to write a query which filters news by date.

Comment: question is about retrieving and also displaying the news, that's why i asked for the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from news where startdate >= now() and enddate <= now() limit 1
```

You'll have to change table and columns name.

Comment: like I said, you must adapt it to your own database structure and eventually to your mysql version. If you give more informations, I can update it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've just mixed up the operators. 
`Today` should be after the `startdate`, doens't it?

```
SELECT id, title FROM news WHERE startDate <= CURDATE() AND
expiryDate >= CURDATE() AND status='Active' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

`SELECT id, title FROM news WHERE now() between startDate AND
expiryDate AND status='Active' ORDER BY id DESC`